# Add button to div problem

Tags: dojo

I have div like

```
var d=dojo.byId('elem');
```

and I want to put three buttons in d from my code ( when I click on some other div, I have connect on click event). 
I tried

```
var button = new dijit.form.Button({
            label: "Click me!",
            onClick: function() {
            }
        },
        "progButtonNode");
```

and

```
d.appendChild(button);
```

but it doesn't work. Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either:

```
var button = new dijit.form.Button({
            id: "progButtonNode",
            label: "Click me!",
            onClick: function() {
            }
        }, d);
```

or

```
var button = new dijit.form.Button({
            id: "progButtonNode",
            label: "Click me!",
            onClick: function() {
            }
        });

d.appendChild(button.domNode);   // Should use dojo.place()
```

The second parameter of a dijit is the container DOM node (in your case "elem"), not your dijit's node.

The object returned is a *dijit object*, **not** a DOM node.  Use the "domNode" property to get that dijit's DOM node.

Be careful to avoid having multiple buttons with the same id.  Should generate a new id for each button, or let dijit generates them for you.

Answer (score 1):

To create dojo button programmatically, node "progButtonNode" must exist on page. For example 
  HTML:
...
<body>
    <button id="progButtonNode" type="button">
    </button>
</body>
...

Javascript:

```
...
  dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");

            dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
                // Create a button programmatically:
                var button = new dijit.form.Button({
                    label: "Click me!",
                    onClick: function() {
                        // Do something:
                        dojo.byId("result1").innerHTML += "Thank you! ";
                    }
                },
                "progButtonNode");

            });
...
```

Dojo button [examples](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/form/Button)